# Phonegap Android application restarting instead of resuming, although it was not killed by the OS

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an Phonegap 1.5/Android application.

My client reports that, when he leaves the app using the Home button, and then relaunches it using the app icon, the app relaunches from the start instead of resuming. However, when he holds the home button, the app appears in the recent apps, and when he accesses the app through this menu, the app resumes in the expected way.

I thought this could be linked to the app being automatically closed by the OS due to a lack of memory, but if that was the case the app shouldn't resume when clicked in the recent apps.

I could not reproduce the bug on my Sony Ericsson XPERIA with Android 2.3.4, the client has experienced this behaviour on a Motorola Defy and on another phone (i'll add the reference of the other phone and the OS versions as soon as I get them).

The initialization process of the app is declared this way :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', _onDeviceReady, false);
}, false);
```

Could this be fixed by attaching the processes to other events (although I doubt it, the app really seems to be relaunched from the start) ?

Is there a declaration  to make in the Android Manifest to prevent this behavior ?

Here is the activity signature in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".MyAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" 
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
     <intent-filter>
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Is that a known bug in some Android phones/versions ?

**Edit** : holding the home button does not display the currently running apps but the recent apps. Why would the behavior in that menu be different from the main icon ?

Comment: I've changed the title to be more explicit

Comment: Isn't this just the difference between starting the default activity vs opening a application (possibly from the last known point)?
If you have a previous "session", you can be in a different activity, whereas from the menu you start the default activity? Also, I don't think you see "currently running apps" by longpressing 'home', you should go to the taskmanager for that. doesn't longpressing home just show you 'recently used apps", whether they still run or not?

Comment: That's right, on my phone longpressing 'home' brings me the recent apps. But why would launching from this menu restore the current 'session' and not launching from the icon ? How can I prevent the icon from starting the default activity and make it resume the current session ? Why would the behavior be different on my phone and on my client's phone ? Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, if I knew all that, I'd have given you an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to add the following to the activity tag in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

So it should look like this:

```
<activity android:name="MyApp" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Check out this page for more information on launchMode: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode

Comment: Actually, if you read the android activity docs, singleTask usage seems to be discouraged and setting android:launchMode="singleTop" also solves the issue. The issue described by the OP still happens with cordova 3.3.0 with default settings. If android:launchMode="singleTop" were the default settings for new cordova projects, I really think it could save many headaches!

Answer (score 3):

Hey Lucas do you have:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in your activity tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

As you said the other thing that could be happening is your client's phone is running low on memory and the OS is killing your app to free up memory.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I just added that part of my AndroidManifest.xml in the question. As said in the question, if the OS had killed the app, it shouldn't be able to resume from the "recent apps" menu...

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Comment: Actually the client finally admitted it was him making some errors in the manipulation of his phone... So I don't and will surely never know if there really was some bug or not...

Comment: @Simon: I am having  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in my activity tag, but still app is restarted instead of just resuming.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually by design in Android, where the OS controls the life cycle of the application. You can [find more information here](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: I'm afraid this does not answer my question. The OS controls the life cycle of the Activity, but, as the app appears in the "running apps", and can be resumed from there, so it means the activity was not killed because of a lack of memory.

If it was not killed, why does clicking on the app icon relaunch it ? If this is in the documentation, could you highlight the point that deals with this behaviour because I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try...

Use android:launchMode="singleInstance" in activity tag of your manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note II and I encountered the same problem. So, I modified the AndroidManifest.xml and now it works both on Samsung and HTC Thunderbolt.

Here are the modifications:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

<activity  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```