# Phonegap Android app restarting instead of resuming

Tags: android, cordova

this question was asked 3 times here but no answer.

I´m using Phonegap 2.1 on android device 2.3.6 (Galaxy SII)
I´m also using AdMob Phonegap plugin.

Well the problem is the same as stated by others:

- When trying to resume thru the app icon the app is restarted even though it´s in memory
- When passing thru the task manager it is resumed normally

**My main activity**

```
public class testApp extends DroidGap 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",5000);

    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
    <activity android:name="testApp" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
              />
</application>
```

Thank you for any advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap Android application restarting instead of resuming, although it was not killed by the OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122449/phonegap-android-application-restarting-instead-of-resuming-although-it-was-not)

Answer (score 1):

If you have "Do not keep activities" selected in the Developer Options section in the Settings app, then no matter what you configure your manifest to, all activities will be destroyed when not in use by the user. This applies to PhoneGap apps and native apps.

Answer (score 0):

place `android:launchMode="standard"` in manifest for `testApp` Activity

Comment: The above answer didn't work for me. My app is still getting restarted when resuming after pressing home button on app.