# prevent Android app restart in Intel XDK

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I have compiled my app for Android using Cordoba 3.5. It has a payments function which requires the user at one point to leave the app and enter his bank details on the browser (required). the problem is that if the user is away for more than 4 o 5 minutes the app gets restarted.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122449/phonegap-android-application-restarting-instead-of-resuming-although-it-was-not) says adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"`solves the problem, however i can see no option to add this to the manifest in the Intel XDK. I there any other way to do this?

Comment: "the problem is that if the user is away for more than 4 o 5 minutes the app gets restarted. " -- that is standard for Android apps, in that their processes are terminated when they are in the background for a while. "this answer says adding android:launchMode="singleTask"solves the problem" -- it certainly does not prevent the process from being terminated.

Comment: I beg to disagree with you but that is not true for all apps. There are apps which you can leave open for a long time and they will not restart to their initial state. Take for example FB app. For what i understand that is the very reason there are four states for an app:
http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode Am i missing a point here?

Comment: "that is not true for all apps" -- it is absolutely true that background processes are terminated on Android as needed. "There are apps which you can leave open for a long time and they will not restart to their initial state" -- that is because they are saving and restoring their state. "For what i understand that is the very reason there are four states for an app" -- that blog post does not discuss any "states for an app".

Comment: I think you should store some inline memory for cases like that.. for example on app start check if there is unfinished payment if yes open that payment window etc

Comment: Yes, i think that is the way to go given the previous explanation. Thank you guys. I'll use the local storage.